# Hide user interface menu button

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm running a site in Internet Explorer on Windows Mobile 6.5 on a MC3190. I managed to hide all the controls, except this one button. What registry key controls the button in the bottom right? Or is there another solution? I want to hide it. (sidequestion: what is the name of this button? I had trouble googling information about it)

[image: button]

(sidenote: this is not my image, it's just to demonstrate the bottom right button.)

edit: changing `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\Sip]` `"AllowChange"=dword:00000000` only makes the menu stay opened permanently.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can not hide this 'button'. The IEM6 menu bar is not using standard menu bar of windows embedded handheld but a self drawn graphic.
Possibly you can find out the handle, class and title using either [zDump](http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2009/06/11/zdump-take-a-look-inside-windows-ce/) (a small tool to click foreign windows and inspect them) or the Remote Spy for Windows CE (part of one or more of the WM SDKs).

For a closed down browser you can write a simple app to host a webBrowser control or use one of the ready-to-use kiosk mode browsers.

Comment: when I was trying the kiosk mode, it was just ignoring the fullscreen part in the registry, and thus showing the task bar, thats why Im not using it. any way around that?

Comment: Even if you force IEM to start in fullscreen mode, the user can alyways switch back to standard mode. You need to write an kiosk mode browser or use one like NaurtechCE browser,